# What is the LLVM intermediate representation?

Tags: llvm, intermediate-code

I have tried the [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) demo from *[Try out LLVM and Clang in your browser!](http://llvm.org/demo/)*.

What kind of [IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation) is this? [HIR](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/hir.html), [MIR](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/mir/index.html), or [LIR](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Emahlke/courses/483f06/lectures/483L17.pdf)? The [SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single-assignment_form) representation is usually used in MIR, I think. So, is it an MIR? But it can store the information for dependence analysis. Hence can it be an HIR?

What filename extension actually represents the LLVM IR, *.ll* or *.bc*?

How can I get the symbol table used in LLVM?

Comment: http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html

Comment: Files with textual representation of LLVM IR have `.ll` extension, binary one - `.bc`

Comment: What are HIR, MIR, and LIR?

Comment: HIR = high-level [intermediate representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation). MIR = mid-level intermediate representation. LIR = low-level intermediate representation. [MLIR](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/04/mlir-new-intermediate-representation.html) = multi-level intermediate representation. [Some elaboration](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/8d9i32/hir_vs_mir_vs_lir/) (but note some of the links are broken).

Comment: And [VLIR](https://www.ida.liu.se/~chrke55/courses/ACC/PDF-2012/F1-Multilevel-IR.pdf) = very low-level intermediate representation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not familiar with a single, *strict* definition of what differentiates one level of IR from another, but from what I know it would fall under the MIR category.

- It has SSA form and doesn't have explicit registers, so I would definitely not categorize it as low-level.
- It doesn't have named subelement reference or advanced flow-control constructs, so it wouldn't really fit into HIR, either.

In any case, LLVM IR is typically stored on disk in either text files with **.ll** extension or in binary files with **.bc** extension. Conversion between the two is trivial, and you can just use `llvm-dis` for **bc** -> **ll** and `llvm-as` for **ll** -> **bc**. The binary format is more memory-efficient, while the textual format is human-readable.